# Mysql subtime currenttime - $row['time']

Tags: php, mysql, time

Im building a simple web page. on loading the page the first time I store the current time in a database. When the page is loaded again I want to get the time that has past since the first load.

I figured out I probably have to use SUBTIME to achieve this. so basicly it would be something like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT SUBTIME('now()','time')"); // in this case time is the name of the database row.
```

I looked around on the net but cant find an example that explains me how to do this. Hope anyone can help me out.

Greetings!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 'time' is the name of your database column use backticks instead of quotes to get the value:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT SUBTIME(NOW(),`time`) AS `total_time`");
```

`NOW()` should not be in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use MySQL for this.

retrieve the time from your database

```
$starttime = strtotime($row['time']); // hopefully a datetime value
$endtime = time();
$totaltime = $endtime - $starttime; // gives the time in seconds
```

and then write it back into your database table, or whatever you want to do with that info

Comment: Why wouldn't you use MySQL for this?

Comment: Don't know, I prefer doing time calculations in PHP :-)